# unable to convert string to int when using streamreader

Tags: c#, string, parsing, int

I am having trouble converting a string to an int. Ive looked around and have been told to use the `int.Parse` but it isn't helping.

I have created an object `Winner` that has a `int WinnerScore` and  `string WinnerName`.
I am trying to add these values to an array `Winner[]` before sorting them.

When I run this code it says:

> NullReferenceException was unhandled
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any idea why this is happening?

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("highscores.txt");

for (int u = 0; u < nWinners; u++)
{
    unsortedList[u].WinnerScore = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine()); 
    unsortedList[u].WinnerName = sr.ReadLine(); 
}
sr.Close();
```

Comment: Please add the declaration and the INITIALIZATION of `unsortedList`

Comment: How do you initialize your unsortedList array? It looks like unsortedList[u] = null for some u in <0, nWinners>

Answer (score 1):

With a certain confidence I can suppose that you have declared the array `unsortedList` but you haven't initialized the objects of Winner class that you want to store in that array.

Simply declaring

```
 Winner[] unsortedList = new Winner[100];
```

creates an array that could store 100 instances of Winner but this array is empty, there are no instances of a Winner class in the 100 slots available, they are all null. You should create every single Winner instances that you want to store in the 100 slots of the array.

So, as an example, your code could be rewritten as

```
Winner[] unsortedList = new Winner[nWinners];
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("highscores.txt"))
{
    for (int u = 0; u < nWinners; u++)
    {
        Winner w = new Winner();
        w.WinnerScore = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine()); 
        w.WinnerName = sr.ReadLine(); 
        unsortedList[u] = w;
    }
    sr.Close();
}
```

However, this has the drawback that you need to know, before entering the loop, the exact number of Winner objects required to dimension your array, If, for some reason, you fail to count them correctly, you fall in another problem (Index Out Of Range).

In this case it is always better to use a `List<Winner>` where you don't need to know before hand the exact number of elements

```
List<Winner> unsortedList = new List<Winner>();
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("highscores.txt"))
{
    while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null))
    {
        Winner w = new Winner();
        w.WinnerScore = int.Parse(line); 
        w.WinnerName = sr.ReadLine(); 
        unsortedList.Add(w);
    }
    sr.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var unsortedList = new List<Winner>();

var nWinners = 100;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("highscores.txt"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nWinners; i++)
    {
        var winer = new Winner();
        winer.WinnerScore = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
        winer.WinnerName = sr.ReadLine();
        unsortedList.Add(winer);
    }
    sr.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've left creation as well as initialization:

```
// My suggestion of unsortedList generic type
public struct Winner {
  public int WinnerScore;
  public String WinnerName; 
}

...

// 1. You shoud create unsortedList:
List<Winner> unsortedList = new List<Winner>(); 

// 2. You should also initialize the list with Winner instances
for (int u = 0; u < nWinners; ++u)
  unsortedList.Add(new Winner());

// 3. Only that you can fill unsortedList from file.
//    And you original code becames the correct one
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("highscores.txt")) {
  for (int u = 0; u < nWinners; ++u) {
    unsortedList[u].WinnerScore = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine()); 
    unsortedList[u].WinnerName = sr.ReadLine(); 
  } 
}
```